# Datatables initialization troubles

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to initialize my datatable, but there's no way.
I want to configure 2 things at the same time but I do not know where the problem is.

First:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable({
        "bFilter" : false,               
        "bLengthChange": false
        });
});
```

Second:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );

$('#button').click( function () {
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
} );
```

} );

Either of the two separately work correctly, but if the together do not work.
I have try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable({
        "bFilter" : false,               
        "bLengthChange": false
        });

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $('#button').click( function () {
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
    });
});
```

Where is the problem? How can I combine this two options?

**SOLVED**: One css file was delete.

Comment: Can you create demo using snippet?

Comment: What do you mean?. Why a snippet es necesary?. It hard for me to create a snippet use node and mongodb. Perhaps the code above showed is correct but i have make a mistake in other part of the code?. Too many css or js files?

Comment: Create with fake data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now all is fine. I have just removed one css file. Thank you Just code 9. I have find the problem trying to make the snippet.